# System.StackOverflowException was unhandled - Trying to call forms and I get this error

Tags: vb.net, forms, exception, recursion

Hi I get the error above when I ran this code. When I try to run a VBNet program that has 3 forms.

I'm just trying to pass list Items from one form to another, but I get an error before the program compiles.

```
Public Class frmCart


Dim frmComic As New comicBooks
Dim frmAudio As New audioBooks

Public decSubTotal As Decimal



Private Sub ShowToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowToolStripMenuItem.Click

    frmComic.ShowDialog()

End Sub


Private Sub ShowDialogToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowDialogToolStripMenuItem.Click
    frmAudio.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

End Class

Now the frmComic is

```
Public Class comicBooks

Dim frmCartForm As New frmCart

Public decPrice1 As Decimal = 20.95D
Public decPrice2 As Decimal = 10.50D


Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Select Case lstComicBooks.SelectedItem

        Case "Comic #1 (Print)"
            frmCart.lstProductsSelected.Items.Add("Comic #1")
            frmCart.decSubTotal += decPrice1
        Case "The History of Scotland (Print)"
            frmCart.lstProductsSelected.Items.Add("Comic #2")
            frmCart.decSubTotal += decPrice2
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Comic")
    End Select

End Sub
```

End Class

I don't know why it's recursive if I call the Dialog only once.

Thanks

Comment: you create a form instance variable, `frmCartForm` then proceed to use the default instance (`frmCart`).  Same in the other form - the instances cars are not used.  What line it crashes on would be nice to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid recursion, you should pass the current instance of frmCart into the comicBooks class in the constructor.  Something like this:

```
Public Class frmCart
    Dim frmComic As New comicBooks(Me)   '<--- Pass current form into constructor
End Class

Public Class comicBooks

    Dim frmCartForm As frmCart  '<--- variable to hold passed in form instance

    Public Sub New(cartForm As frmCart)    '<--- Constructor to take instance of form
        Me.frmCartForm = cartForm          '<--- Assign passed in reference to our variable
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        'Use frmCartForm here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Class comicBooks instantiates a new frmCart.
2. frmCart instantiates a new comicBooks
3. Go back to 1

Remove the frmCartForm declaration in comicBooks

Comment: So should I put all the instantiates in a Module?

Comment: Well... I really don't know how your application is supposed to work, but no I don't recommend that.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you were a VB6 developer. Forms work differently now. Forms are not singletons by design. Referencing a form in one class and in another won't be referencing the same form unless it's a globally declared object or you are passing the object from one class to the other.